# Prototype methods not working on textField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This doesn't make any sense to my feeble brain, and I've reached my googlefu limit.

I have a bunch of prototype methods that I use to speed development up, and most of them are attached to `DisplayObject` or `InterActiveObject`. Here's an example of one such prototype:

```
DisplayObject.prototype.$click = function(clicked:Function, released:Function = null):void{
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function():void {
            clicked();
        });

    if(released != null){
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function():void {
            released();
        });
    }
}
```

If I call any `movieClipInstance.$click(someFunction)`, it binds correctly. However, if I attempt to do that on a `TextField` instance, it gives me the following compile-time error.
`Call to a possibly undefined method $click through a reference with static type flash.text:TextField.`

According to the reference, `TextField` inherits `DisplayObject`, but just to be sure I redefined my prototype explicitly for `TextField`s. Still the same error. :(

Comment: I've gone and learned myself up on prototype methods in AS3 and I came up with a disappointing answer. I'll put it below :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always extend TextField and add the methods there.  In fact, you should consider doing this for all the other objects as well:  Extend MovieClip, Sprite, or whatever other DisplayObject you want to add the $click method to.  Then let all your other objects inherit ClickMovie, ClickSprite etc. instead of the generic classes. It should not be a lot more code to write, but your application will be considerably faster and type safe.

You should use prototype only in cases where you have to add or override methods or properties dynamically at runtime.

An in-depth explanation on how inheritance works in AS3 can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=04_OO_Programming_12.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't declare a TextField in the designer to be a subclass of TextField.  If you want custom methods on your text fields, then you can't use the designer to lay out your text fields, and if you want to use the designer to lay out your text fields, then you can't have custom methods on your text fields.  Adobe has successfully made the two features mutually exclusive by not allowing prototype methods on non-dynamic classes; fail.

Comment: You could create an ActionScript hook where you listen for `Event.ADDED` and replace all instances of TextField with your own subclass, though.

Comment: Besides, manipulating classes that are not your own via prototype is not a good idea, anyway - you will lose IDE support, you will have a hard time debugging things, and who knows what might break after the next SDK update...

Comment: Replacing all instances with a hook is not a viable solution, because you'd be overwriting only one of many references to the original text field.  For example, a library symbol of class named "Form" which contains member variables pointing to its child TextFields would hold references to the original TextField objects.  So while you can replace the stage instances with new instances of your TextField subclass automatically with a hook, everything else will still hold references to the original TextField and there is no easy way to update them all automatically.

Comment: In AS2, I could easily create MovieClip.prototype methods such as "attachButton" and TextField.prototype methods like "attachScrollBar".  Now, the only viable solution is to create separate helper classes that accept TextField instances as parameters to achieve this.  It's not that big of a deal, because it's just slightly different syntax, but like extension methods in C#, the syntax is very useful.  In any case, there is simply no viable way to use the IDE to lay out AND configure (font, size, etc.) your text fields AND use a custom subclass.

Comment: That subclass of MovieClip can be modified, though, so you can dynamically assign those references.

Comment: "attachScrollBar" makes no sense - if anything, the scrollbar should know about the text field, but not vice versa.

Comment: It makes sense, because you add a scroll bar to an existing textfield.  For example, there's a "ScrollBars" properties on UI control in .NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.scrollbars.aspx), and you can pick whether it has vertical or horizontal scrolling or both or none.  "attachScrollBar" therefore, makes sense as a method on a TextField, because it adds a scroll bar to it.  A textfield therefore would need to know about the scrollbar, so it can track them being added or removed to avoid adding duplicates or trying to remove one that doesn't exist.

Comment: As for MovieClip being subclassed, you would have to write special code for every one of them to know which member variables need updated, and if you have some ADDED listener attached to the stage to handle the conversion automatically, that listener would have to communicate the new instances to the methods of the MovieClip subclasses that handle updating the member variables references for that specific class, and you'd have to communicate both the old and new references in pairs so it knows which variable should acquire which reference.  It's too much work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14357/discussion-between-weltraumpirat-and-triynko)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that a hook won't work, because by the time the TextField instance is added to the stage... that instance may have already existed a long time and many things may have referenced it.  There's no magical automated way to just "transform" all TextFields in the IDE into some subclass.  That "Form" class, for example, could have created its own scrollbars, which could have attached listeners to the original TextFields long before the ADDED event even occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, prototype methods can only be assigned to classes declared with the `dynamic` keyword. Went to the reference to see if my experiences matched that assertion and sure enough `TextField` is defined as `public class TextField`. `MoveClip` on the otherhand is defined as `public dynamic class MovieClip`

Seems a bit wonky to me that a non dynamic class still can't access the prototype methods of its dynamic ancestors though. Inheritance strikes again!